# French characters like é not supported in spring-integration http outbound gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, resteasy

I am trying to send this string " de caisse a ét**é** enregistr***é*** " from http outbound gateway.This string contains french character(é).I am getting an error with response code as 400(bad request)

However,when i tried the same from rest easy client framework i am getting a success code(200).

Is there something i am missing in my spring integration configuration. ?

Sharing the configuration

```html
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="xtifygateway"
                           
  request-channel="xtifyrequestchannel" request-factory="requestFactory" 
                           
  url="${xtifyUrl}" http-method="POST">
  
  </int-http:outbound-gateway>




<int:header-enricher input-channel="requestchannel" 
                     output-channel="xtifyrequestchannel">
<int:header
        name="Content-Type"
        value="application/json"/>
        </int:header-enricher
  
  

<bean id="requestFactory"
  class="org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory">
  <property name="connectTimeout" value="${timeout}" />
  <property name="readTimeout" value="${timeout}" />
   </bean>
```

Comment: Would be better if your trace your request with something like wireshark and compare them between each other. Would mind also share the stacktrace after that 400 code? What doesn't the server like in your request? Maybe you have just missed some HTTP header, which is the default from the Rest Easy...

Comment: From other hand: you haven't confirmed that it works without french characters... So, the problem with the unexpected characters isn't obvious.

Comment: Artem,I will share the stacktrace on monday. Without french characters,everything is working fine.

Comment: Hi..I have shared the log causing 400 code in https://gist.github.com/anonymous/46cfc89746b5417dc37b80aeabd5bc06. Can you please have a look ?

Comment: M-m-m. As you see it isn't helpful. Or you should take a look into the error handling for the HTTP to have more info ab out that `400`. Or would be better to consult with your server provider to determine what's wrong with your french symbols. And you haven't shared the wireshark investigation from your side. Right now we only read tea leaves from our side, because the problem is out there.

Comment: Wireshark is somehow having some issues in my linux system Artem,sorry for that...:( I have contacted server provider and waiting for there response.But i am still confused why only spring is throwing 400 when rest easy and also using java's buffered writer are resulting in 202 (success) for the same content ! Do you have any luck on finding this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the charset from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 in java code solved the issue.

```
try
   {
       message= new String(message.getBytes("UTF-8"),"ISO-8859-1");
   }
   catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1)
   {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e1.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try setting the charset

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="xtifygateway"

request-channel="xtifyrequestchannel" request-factory="requestFactory" charset="UTF-8"

url="${xtifyUrl}" http-method="POST">

  </int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Comment: It is like that by default: `private volatile Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");`